# jQuery hide post based on UID

Tags: jquery

I want to hide DIV based on User ID with one click button.

```
<div class="click_me" id="<?php echo $uid; ?>">Click me for hide</div>

<div class="post" id="post<?php echo $uid; ?>">
     bla bla
</div>

<div class="post" id="post<?php echo $uid; ?>">
     bla bla
</div>

<div class="post" id="post<?php echo $uid; ?>">
     bla bla
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".click_me").click(function()
{
     var ID = $(this).attr("id");

     $("#post"+ID).hide();
}
```

When I try that above code. It just hide 1 post not all that same UID.

So how can I hide all if UID is same?

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique** - when you use an id selector it will return only the first element with the given id(same as `document.querySelector()`) - If your case if you want to group similar elements use a class value of another custom attribute

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use classes to control multiple elements, below is the code, [or try this fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/6j2bwyf1/)
the fiddle uses 77 in place of your php generated id for demonstration purposes only

```
$(".click_me").on('click', function() 
{
     var ID = $(this).attr("id");
     $(".post"+ID).hide();
});
```

and change these to:

```
<div class="post<?php echo $uid; ?>">
     bla bla
</div>

<div class="post<?php echo $uid; ?>">
     bla bla
</div>

<div class="post<?php echo $uid; ?>">
     bla bla
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use classes instead of id's, as id's are meant to be unique identifiers for webpage elements.

Does the following help? (untested)

HTML:

```
<div class="click_me" data-userId="<?php echo $uclass; ?>">Click me for hclasse</div>

<div class="post <?php echo $uclass; ?>">
     bla bla
</div>

<div class="post <?php echo $uclass; ?>">
     bla bla
</div>

<div class="post <?php echo $uclass; ?>">
     bla bla
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".click_me").click(function()
{
     var userId = $(this).attr("data-userId");

     $(".post"+userId).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this, as `id` is unique in dom tree, you can use data- to mark that record and get the element by attribute

```
<div class="post" data-uuid="post<?php echo $uid; ?>">
     bla bla
</div>

<div class="post" data-uuid="post<?php echo $uid; ?>">
     bla bla
</div>

<div class="post" data-uuid="post<?php echo $uid; ?>">
     bla bla
</div>

  $(".click_me").click(function() {
         var ID = $(this).attr("id");
         var uuid='post'+ID;
         $("div.post[data-uuid='"+uuid+"']").hide();
    }
```